# Now that Mac OS X Server is an app within OSX, how would I run it on a Windows machine?

Tags: home-server, osx-server

Previous versions of OS X server were stadandalone installations that could be installed on any machine and run as a separate operating system. However, Lion Server is a different story as it is now an app within OS X itself. In short, how would I be able to run OS X Lion Server on a Windows installation or on Windows hardware?

Comment: Wouldn't running Lion as a virtual machine allow you to use it's server from within it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Apps compiled for OS X cannot be run on Windows, and likewise, Windows programs don't run on OS X. If you want to use Lion Server, you will need to run it from OS X on Apple hardware.

Comment: Not _exactly_ what I was looking for but satisfied my terrible explaination of my question.